# how to replace display array list equals another array list values

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm new for android application developing.how to replace display array list equals another array list values.

---

**Code:**

```
String[] first={"50-100","100-200","200-300","400-500","600-700","800-900"};

String[] second={"100","200","300","500","700","900"};
```

---

my requirement is :
first array list values display in drop down list but when I'm click first array list value "50-100" then read "100"

Comment: can you please elaborate the situation a bit better. i read it twice but still confused. thanks \

Comment: Please post some code showing what you have tried before asking people to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an OnItemClickListener to handle the user choice.

```
yourFirstList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {  
          //the index from your first list is i
          String newValue = second[i];
          yourTextView.setText(newValue);
      }
});
```